# Which WebGL framework should i learn?

Tags: webgl

I find a framework list on
http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/User_Contributions#Frameworks

However, what is different of them?
I read some article said, WebGL is driven by low level language, WebGL Framework just make it to high level language to easy implementation.

I am already have much jQuery,jQueryUI, C# background, which one should i pick?

Comment: What will you be using it for, and how much 3D experience do you have?  Each library has a mixture of strengths and weaknesses.  For example, GLGE is quite game-oriented, PhiloGL is for data visualisation, SceneJS is for scene graphs, three.js is more general-purpose.

Answer (score 11):

I cannot speak from experience as I am in the same boat as you, looking for a WebGL framework to use. So far in my research of the various frameworks I'm leaning toward Three.Js

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Comment: I did my WebGL project using Three.js and very recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

WebGL is indeed low-level. That's not a problem if you already have the tools and functions in place to manage your scene data (meshes, materials, shaders, rendering optimizations, and so forth). It just means you need to be familiar with the graphics pipeline, how it works, how best to optimize it and what the subtle bugs and workarounds are from one video card driver to the next.

In terms of frameworks, I'm afraid I'm a bit biased, since I'm authoring one. :)

I've been putting a lot of effort into Jax ( http://blog.jaxgl.com/what-is-jax/ ) to make it as powerful, simple and flexible a framework as possible. It borrows a lot of its key concepts from Ruby on Rails, using Ruby in the background to generate and automate as much as possible. This lets the developer (you) get down to business right away, instead of fiddling with implementation details. The end result is 100% HTML and JavaScript, so there's no need to fret over compatibility. If you're up for trying something new, give Jax a shot. The link above talks more about the details, and I've recently put a "Quick-Start" page online ( http://jaxgl.com ) if you'd just like to hurry up and render something!

Comment: It seems to be the only one that integrates nicely with Ruby on Rails.