# What should i use webgl framework?

Tags: frameworks, webgl

I want to use webgl framework. But as a beginner I don't know much about this.
I examined GLGE, Three.js, SceneJS.

So, I have following questions:

1. Do GLGE use Scenegraph?
2. Why ThreeJS have active discussion?

What is my best choice?

I want to choose the framework of good condition.

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301967/which-webgl-framework-should-i-learn, but the answer is still stabilizing...

Comment: Three.js is the best around in my opinion, but I recommend you to start building your own webgl framework from the ground up, It may take more time and required more knowledge, but it worth in the long run and may improve your skills.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Which WebGL framework should i learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301967/which-webgl-framework-should-i-learn), but the answer to "what is the best choice?" or "what framework is in good condition?" is still changing pretty rapidly, so that answer may no longer be very helpful.

I can say that Three.js has lots of cool demos, is pretty widely used, and is actively maintained. But its API is still changing a lot, and is not documented well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to visualize data in 3d, you should look at the X toolkit ( http://goXTK.com ). It provides a very simple API and only little overhead.

If you want to develop a game, Three.js is the way to go.. :)

For disclosure, I am part of the XTK developers team.